# Shifting focus to next Textfield

Tags: ios

I have a set of 4 textfields. I have applied certain restriction to these textfields which can be easily understood by the code below.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString * newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if (string.length==0) {
        return YES;
    }


    if (textField == txt_mins) {
        return [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] setNumberFormat:textField newString:newString
        IntegerLimit:5 FractionLimit:2 NumberType:2];
    }
    else if (textField == txt_units){
        return [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] setNumberFormat:textField newString:newString 
        IntegerLimit:5 FractionLimit:2 NumberType:2];
    }
    // Below logic is for All 4 Modifer Textfields
    // we are restricting the user to enter only max 2 characters in modifier textfields and
     also automatically
    // converting each entered character to the uppercase string.
    if (textField==txt_modifier1 || textField==txt_modifier2 || textField==txt_modifier3 ||
     textField==txt_modifier4) {
        // This condition is restricting the user from entering the special characters in the
        modifier textfield.
        if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] 
        invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
            // There are non-alphanumeric characters in the replacement string
            return NO;
        }
        else{
        NSString *result = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range 
        withString:string.uppercaseString];
        if (result.length <= 2)
            textField.text = result;
        return NO;
       }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

What I actually want is that for txt_modifier1. As soon as I type my two characters in the textfield the focus should shift to the next textfield that is txt_modifier2 and similarly for the other modifier text fields. I have made these restrictions in shouldChangeCharactersInRange: method. Please suggest the way to handle this enhancement in my code.

Comment: Use resignFirstResponder on the textfield that has the focus and becomeFirstResponder on the textfield that you want to assume the focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@property UIView *firstResponder;

- (void) toggleTextfield 
{
    NSInteger nextTag = self.firstResponder.tag;
    nextTag += 1;
    UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:nextTag];  
    if (nextTextField)  
    {  
        [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];  
    }  
}
```

assign tag value to all the textfields as u want use them.
call this method when u want to shift the focus.

add this line in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`

```
self.firstResponder = textField;

Replace this code 
if (result.length <= 2)
  textField.text = result  
return NO; 

with 

 if (result.length <= 2) 
        textField.text = result; 
    else [self toggleTextfield]; 

and add this function - 

(void)textFieldDidBeginEditienter code hereng:(UITextField *)textField   
{  
     self.firstResponder = textField;   
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your explanation and show me how to apply this with respect to my code. It will be a great help!

Comment: This is working fine but it is not transferring the focus to the next textfield just after typing two characters in the first text field. As soon as I start typing the third character in the textfield then it shifts the focus and starts typing in the next textfield. What I actually want is the automatic transfer of focus as soon as I type the second character in my textfield. So If you can help in this then it will be great. thanks for the above code man!

Comment: yeah! thanks mate it is working very fine!. Now I have one more functionality to employ in this. As soon as I remove the values from any middle text field. For example If I am removing the values from the second textfield then the value from the 3rd and 4th text field should be removed. This is same for every textfield that on removing the middle one all the subsequent text field values should be removed. Thanks a lot in advance for your efforts.

Comment: You should accept this answer as it works for what u asked in main question. And you should ask a new question for this.

Comment: Yeah! I have accepted your answer. Sorry for the negligence on my part. Try to look into the above mentioned problem as mentioning in another question will have me to again explain the whole problem!. Further help from your side will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you might check for textField is empty or not in 
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField.. if yes then remove text from the subsequent fields. But i am not sure about it. You can give it a try. and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Hi! BS I am having a problem with the code that u told above. First of all it is not restricting the length of the text to 2 in the last text field and I can type as many characters in the last textfield.             Secondly, After shifting the focus to the next field, If I again came back to the previous textfield then it is allowing me to enter more than 2 characters. Can u help me to get out of this situation. it will be greatly helpful.

Comment: But yestereday you told that it was working , what happened now ?
did you change anything ?

Comment: No i didn't change anything. i just looked into the forward flow and didn't checked for the backward flow after going forward if I want to come back for those textfields then it will allow me to enter more than two characters!. I hope you understood the problem.

Comment: I don't think it should matter that u are going forward or backword. cuz u r checking the string length. In both case it will be the same.

Comment: no! but after shifting the focus to the next text field If I am again manually coming back to the previous text field then it is allowing me to enter more than 2 characters. i don't what is causing the problem but it is happening in this way only. Moreover in fourth textfield it is not restricting to 2 characters even on the first time as it has no  next text field to shift.

Comment: Moreover due to the line " self.firstResponder = textField; " in the didBeginEditing method my other textfields are becoming dormant i.e I am not able to work on that or tap on that.

Comment: It shouldn't cause a problem. I used it myself. ask a new question which have ur code. I will try to answer it after seeing ur other code.

Comment: I have added a new question with the new code..You can see it there and can solve the problem there only. thanks for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (textField==txt_modifier1)
{
 // This condition is restricting the user from entering the special characters in the
    modifier textfield.
    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] 
    invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
        // There are non-alphanumeric characters in the replacement string
        return NO;
    }
    else{
    NSString *result = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range 
    withString:string.uppercaseString];
    if (result.length <= 2)
        textField.text = result;
    else
    [txt_modifier2 becomeFirstresponder];

    return NO;
   }
}
else if( textField==txt_modifier2 )
{
same code of above block just change the text filed on which you want to focus next
}
else if(textField==txt_modifier3 )
{
same code of above block just change the text filed on which you want to focus next
}
else if(textField==txt_modifier4) 
{
same code of above block just change the text filed on which you want to focus next
}
```

Hope this helps you.Let me know the result